# Python igraph for windows 64bit

Tags: python, igraph, python-3.4

I am looking for python-igraph package for windows 64bits. I have installed python 3.4 and it seems that I can not find proper igraph installation package for it. I have crawled all webpages and still could not find what I am looking for. 
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Christoph Gohlke's page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) contains a Python wheel compiled for Python 3.4 on a 64-bit Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Tamas, you should download wheel packages from the link and use pip to install them.